# Swift iOS : Find parse users via UISearchBar and dysplay results in a table view

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uisearchbar

i trie to find parse users via UISearchBar and display results in a table view.
When i heat search, nothing happened...
My idea was to use the searchText.text as a query to PFUser.

Should i try to use searchBar with search display controller instead ?
Any idea ?

```
import UIKit


  class AllFriendsTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate,      UISearchDisplayDelegate {
@IBOutlet var SearchDisplay: UISearchDisplayController!



var userList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


 func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar!) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func searchBarShouldEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar!) -> Bool {
    return true

}

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, textDidChange searchText: String!) {
    loadUser()
}



@IBOutlet var searchText: UISearchBar!



func loadUser () {

    userList.removeAllObjects()
    var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findUser.whereKey("username", equalTo: searchText.text)


    findUser.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if !(error != nil) {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("succesfull load Users")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object  in objects  {
                self.userList.addObject(object)
                println("users added to userlist")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("error loadind user ")
            println("error")
        }

    }
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView {
        return userList.count
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {



    let cell: AllFirendsTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as AllFirendsTableViewCell


    let users:PFObject = self.userList.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject


    var findUserName:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findUserName.whereKey("username", containsString: searchText.text)



    findUserName.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

        if !(error != nil) {

            if let user:PFUser = users as? PFUser {
                cell.userNameTextField.text = user.username
                println("user exist")
                // define avatar poster

                if let avatarImage:PFFile = user["profileImage"] as? PFFile {
                    avatarImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData:NSData!, error:NSError!)-> Void in

                        if !(error != nil) {

                            let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)


                            cell.avatarImage.image = image as UIImage
                            cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = 24
                            cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true

                        }

                    }

                }
                else {
                    cell.avatarImage.image = UIImage(named: "Avatar-1")
                    cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = 24
                    cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
                }
            }

        }


    }

  return cell

}



override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = false
    loadUser()

}


override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func viewDidLoad() {


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

}

Comment: You should search for users when search button is tapped, but currently you do it in a cellForRow method. This is wrong. There is an article about searchbar at raywenderlich.com, read it.

Comment: thanks but i ve allready read this tuto. If i do it like raywenderlich.com, i have to download all parse user and then filter the result. I would prefer to download only the users who matches the searchText.text.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. I checked your code and it looks OK.

Comment: ok but i can't see any results  in the table view. Something is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be due to you attempting to reload the tableview from the background thread that your network request occurs on.  UI updates should happen from the main thread.

In your `loadUser()` function try doing your tableview reload from the main thread, as follows:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

That may fix your issue.

Comment: Those withBlock: methods from parse run the block on the main thread.